Answer release-it command line prompts with options?
Does release-it have command line options that can be substituted for answers to the prompts?
For example --push instead of saying yes to push.

Feature Request: https://github.com/release-it/release-it/issues/1118

Yes.  So for example suppose it has been configured to push to Github by default.
    "github": {
      "release": true
    },

And we want to skip answering questions, but not push.  We can run the release it like this.
npx release-it --ci --no-git.push

Thanks to Lars for pointing this out and the configuration documentation is here.
